# Pandas Date %y defaults to 20xx instead of 19xx

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a date like: 28.01.58

I am trying to convert using:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d.%m.%y')
```

Pandas returns: 2058-01-28

My expected return: 1958-01-28

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately because of Y2K shenanigans, pandas works implicitly with 2 digit years, as a fix for this you can try

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str[:-2]+'20'+df['date'].str[-2:], format='%d.%m.%y')
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply! im getting following error: File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/strptime.pyx", line 156, in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 58